# how to get URL value in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

So, i tried laravel and i got stuck when i want to get URL value as a value for my database. Here is the code in my controller.

```
public function store(Request $request, $shoe_id)
{
    //Insert Data
    $cart = new Cart;
    
    $cart->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $cart->shoe_id = $shoe_id;
    $cart->quantity = $request->quan;

    $cart->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

and here is the problem i've encountered:
[it says that the {shoe_id} is string where i wanted to be an integer from the URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GImDY.png)

Here what my website looks like:
[My blade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlsYR.jpg)

Here is my web.php:

```
Route::get('/','homeController@main')->name('home');
Route::get('/home','homeController@main')->name('home');
Route::get('/detail/{shoe_id}', 'homeController@detail');
Route::get('/cart/{shoe_id}','CartController@show');
Route::post('/cart/{shoe_id}','CartController@store');
```

Here is my blade:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div style="text-align:center;">
                    <img src="{{ asset("$cart->shoe_image") }}" alt="" style=" width:350px; height:350px;">
                    <div class="card-header">{{$cart->shoe_name}}</div>
                    <div class="card-header">${{$cart->shoe_price}}</div>
                    <div class="card-header">{{$cart->shoe_description}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-header form-group">
                    <form method="POST" action="/cart/{shoe_id}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input class = "form-control" type="text" id="quantity" name="quan"><br><br>
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="addcart">Add to Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    
                    {{-- <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Add to Cart</a> --}}
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

what i want to do: input the inputted data to database. My database has table called cart with attribute of id, user_id, shoe_id.

Comment: please show you route implementation and how do you call the url

Comment: Post your blade view with the form and the route declaration in routes (web.php) file in code blocks  - please do not attach image

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what is `{shoe_id}` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form action you should provide the actual value for the shoe_id then it will work as expected. `action="/cart/{{ $cart->shoe_id }}"`

```php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div style="text-align:center;">
                    <img src="{{ asset("$cart->shoe_image") }}" alt="" style=" width:350px; height:350px;">
                    <div class="card-header">{{$cart->shoe_name}}</div>
                    <div class="card-header">${{$cart->shoe_price}}</div>
                    <div class="card-header">{{$cart->shoe_description}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-header form-group">
                    <form method="POST" action="/cart/{{ $cart->shoe_id }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input class = "form-control" type="text" id="quantity" name="quan"><br><br>
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="addcart">Add to Cart</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    
                    {{-- <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Add to Cart</a> --}}
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: `{$cart->shoe_id}` will be `{{ $cart->shoe_id }}`

Comment: @sta Yep sorry my bad. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: still occured the problem. What about my controller? how to get the given {{ $cart->shoe_id }}

Comment: What is the value of `dd($shoe_id)` in the store method? It should get the value you are passing from the blade view as route parameter

Comment: this is the value: "{shoe_id}"

Comment: Very strange. Can you open up devtools and look at the network tab to see what is the url to which post request is made when you submit the form. Also you need to check for the value of $cart->shoe_id in the blade {{ dd($cart->shoe_id) }} in the blade file anywhere and see

Comment: somehow, the problem is fixed. Idk what i did there, but thank you for the help